# excel data filtration using oledb from huge excel files size approx (200mb) using c# (ADO)

Tags: c#, ado.net, oledb

my ado application **requires to read data from one xlsx file(Approx 10-20MB min**) and then **process the data row by row and compare with another xlsx file( approx size 250 MB min) containing over 1000000 rows with 63 columns (work like database)**. when i try to read the database file (250 MB) and run the oledb data queries on it, it's working so strange, **its only give the first matched data from the database file. but if i opened that xlsx database file in office excel and then run my application its return all matched data from the database file without changing any code.**

i already checked my dataquery its working fine in server Explorer and returns the complete result.

this process also very time consuming , i already tried openxml sax mathod to resolve the performance issue as well, but its not worked too. even it takes more time compare to oledb to read the excel.

i also have two another issues in my application,

1. sometime oledb returns an exception 'System resource exceeded'  and
2. some time return 'internal ole automation error' .

i also tried google to resolve these issue but i didn't find any solution for my problem.

is there any solution to resolve these issues. please help me. any suggestion appreciated but please remember one thing i can't change any xlsx table format because i don't have rights, these xlsx files automatically generated by another tools by our sourcing partners.

thanks.